# How to start a new project in GAS linked to a Google Sheets when the first project already exists?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I need two different projects but linked to the same *Google Sheets*.

So for that I used to create the first project just by clicking on `Extensions > Apps Script` on *Google Sheets* and then on *Legacy Editor* clicking on `File > New > Project` on image below is `Arquivo > Novo > Projeto`:

[image]

But what about in the New Editor, where do I find this option?

There is no common menu on this new IDE and don't exist the option in the IDE action menu (`F1`).

Comment: Hi. Have you tried the [Apps Script dashboard](https://script.google.com/home)? or [Standalone Scripts](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/standalone) in the documentation?

Comment: Hi @Tedinoz I've tried looking through the dashboard but I haven't found how to create a new project linked to a spreadsheet that already has a GAS project created. Regarding Standalone, as I mentioned in my question, I need the second project to also be linked to the spreadsheet.

Comment: Hi. I'm not so sure that you can have multiple projects "bound" to  the same spreadsheet. BUT, you _can_ have a standalone project that opens and defines a specific spreadsheet. Once you've created that initial linkage, you can do (almost??) anything in the unbound project that you can do in the bound project.

Comment: You said _I need two different projects but linked to the same Google Sheets_ but you didn't discuss the context/ rationale, etc. Would you care to discuss the reason for this. Sometimes there is more than one way to 'skin a cat', so to speak.

Comment: Hello @Tedinoz , there is a way to do it in the old editor (in the second paragraph I added the step by step that we can do this), but in the new editor I didn't find the option. (and since the old editor will only continue to work until September, I'm relearning)

Regarding the reason, it is because of the greater speed in collecting and recording data in the spreadsheet compared to having to open it through the API or the ID.

Comment: Related: [New Google Apps Script Editor - Additional Bound Projects?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65686292/1330560). This is a step by-step workaround. Sounds just what you need. It's on StackOverflow.

Comment: That was exactly the search key word that my fail English didn't remind me of → "Additional Bound", thank you very much @Tedinoz . Apparently I'll have to open a feature request to the ```File > New > Project``` return, because cloning the project takes libraries and special configurations that may be useless in the new project. Thanks for helping me find this related question, it has already helped me enormously!

Comment: Beaut. Since that answer is on StackOverflow, once you have figured out the process why not answer your own question, particularly if you noticed any wrinkles that weren't expected. It's all about paying it forward.